# SAP HANA or Hadoop?

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

this is a question regarding a career choice. I am a fresher and I recently joined an MNC in Data Engineering team. There I was offered training in either Hadoop or SAP HANA. I am in doubt as to which one should I choose. Can anyone help me make the right choice? Which of these two has better scope based on the current trend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really, really bothers me when people vote to close questions like this. Just goes to show that the folks on the site are out-of-touch with reality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking for current trends, you would choose Hadoop without question. The issue with items like SAP, SAS (or other massive enterprise packages like that) is that they are all 4th generation programming languages with a lot of overhead and the corresponding licensing fees. I would be concerned that more & more enterprises will find themselves moving towards Hadoop and away from the enterprise packages. I see those packages edging more and more towards the trend of serving as a "data lake" whereas Hadoop will be more of an active, day-to-day environment relied on for data science (and that's a good thing!).